# Ball Game-Probability-Maximum number of balls-

Tags: probability, random-variables, random-walk, gambling

Your friend will put 100 balls with 5 different colors in a bag and tell you the number of balls for each color. Then you will randomly choose a ball and guess its color. Afterr seeing the ball, if your guess is correct, you will take the ball. If not, then your friend will take the ball. This game will continue until all the balls are taken. Both of you try to get as many balls as you can.

What is the maximum number of balls your friend can take?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I am confused that the maximum number of balls in the question means the Expected value of random variables? It seems easy but the result I have found does not make any sense.

Comment: Maximum should mean the greatest possible, expected value should mean the average (assuming this game is played often).  Here, for instance, your friend should never get $100$ since, at least, you'll always know the color of the final ball.  So the maximum is $≤99$.

Comment: Go ahead and edit your attempt in, even if it is wrong. We appreciate your effort here on MSE!

Comment: I think that is 99 but I could not verify it so I am not sure about the answer. Even if there is a small probability, he can take 99 balls .

Comment: For instance, let's suppose the friend decides the numbers of each color as 20. At first step, I can know the ball drawn with 20/100 probability whereas with  (1-20/100)=80/100 I can not. The probability I can not predict the drawn ball, (80/100)*(79/99)*(78/98)*(77/97)*(76/96)*(76/95).................

Comment: What happens after the 80th ball?

Comment: Mystring might be 123451234512345..... So the 81thball can start with 1. The numbers denote the colours.

Comment: There are at least $20$ balls of at least one color.  I can guess that color every time and take $20$ balls for sure.

Comment: (20,20,20,20,20), (20,19,20,20,20), (20,19,19,20,20), (20,19,19, 19,20), (19,19,19,19,20), (19,19,19,19,19),.................................. (2,2,2,2,2), (1,2,2,2,2), (1,2,1,2,2), (1,1,1,2,2), (0,1,1,2,2), .......... (0,0,0,1,1), (0,0,0,0,1)

Comment: @Mubay Please share your thoughts and attempts in the body of your post by editing it.

Comment: Do I have to guess at random, or can I guess systematically?

Answer (score 0):

This is a *worst case* problem. Therefore we don't have to compute probabilities or expectations.

It may very well be that the last two remaining balls are of different colors; hence we have different colors available at each of the first $98$ steps. It may be that you guess wrong at each of these steps, even if you  choose each time the color with the largest number of remaining balls. You then may make the wrong choice also on the $99^{\rm th}$ step, so that your friend now has $99$ balls. At this point you know the color of the last remaining ball, and you will therefore "guess" its color correctly. The answer to the question therefore is $99$.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe The question says,"Your friend will put 100 balls with 5 different colors in a bag *and tell you the number of balls for each color.*"

Comment: If I'm allowed to guess systematically on the last ball, why can't I guess systematically every time?  I guess the most frequent color every time, and collect at least $20$ balls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree with you. I have written simulation code to see it is 99.